# How to get only elements of a specific type in a collection in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, set, tuples

I have a value in Scala which is a `Set` of tuples of `Long` and `Double`, and I have to assign the Long values to a new set to be able to look for its intersection with another set of Long values.

So my sets would be

```
firstSet : Set[(Long, Double)]
secondSet : Set[Long]
```

I want to put the `Long` values of the `firstSet` in a new set to apply the intersect method with `secondSet` as argument.

Is it possible to do it in an efficient way? I'm very new to Scala so I don't just want to do a bunch of nested If statements.

Comment: You just need to `map` on the first `Set`

Comment: and `Set` has an `intersect` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` to get the first `Long` value from each Tuple and create a new set. Note the elements in the Tuple are accesses with `._1`, `._2` and so on.

```
val firstSet = Set((0l,0.0), (1l, 1.0))
val firtSet: Set[(Long, Double)] = Set((0,0.0), (1,1.0))

firstSet.map(t => t._1)
val res5: Set[Long] = Set(0, 1)
```

Then you use this result to intersect with the other set